# Rigid Body and Invisible Object Collision

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, transparency, rigid-body-simulation

Let us assume I have a brick wall (rigid body) that I want to get smashed with an object (in a rigid body simulation). I want this object to be invisible in the render. Is that possible? How do I do that?

Comment: Via shaders? Couldn't you just turn up the transparency or use a _Transparent BSDF_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now, I see no reason why you couldn't add a *Transparent BSDF* shader to the smashy object.

*View:*

[image]

*Render:*

[image]

*Animation with transparent smashy thing:*

[image]

My .blend file:

[image]

Also, as [lemon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/24625/lemon) points out, in the *Properties panel > Object tab > Cycles Settings dropdown*, you could uncheck the *Camera* checkbox. If you follow this course, though, you will have a disembodied shadow.

[image]

As [Nathan Craddock](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/5505/nathan-craddock) adds, you can also turn off *Render Visibility* in the *Outliner*.

[image]

Comment: You can also simply disable the camera ray visibility in the Cycles settings of the object

Comment: @lemon Very true. Added your advice.

Comment: You can also turn off renderability in the outliner.

Comment: @NathanCraddock Thanks! Added that in, too.

Comment: @NathanCraddock If I turn off render visibility I will have my object not rendered, do I ?

Comment: @OldMan it just won't be visible. It will still interact.

Comment: @NathanCraddock I tested it and you are right.  I always thought the object was excluded from the render