# Invisible wall in cycle

Tags: collision

I have a basic cube mesh that i currently use as a wall

And a basic ball mesh deforming itself on it as my animation

How can make the cube invisible BUT keeping the interactions between the two objects as i render in cycles?

Comment: Restrict the visibility for camera. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48122/how-can-i-make-an-object-invisible-when-i-render-in-cycles

Comment: Or just give it a transparent shader. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58928/rigid-body-and-invisible-object-collision/58931#58931